# PhpStorm via phpunit.phar - Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php)

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpstorm

1. I have downloaded phpunit.phar from official website https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
   v4.6

PhpStorm v8.0.3 (PS-139.1348, February 12, 2015)

2. Configured phpunit settings in PhpStorm. Set "Path to phpunit.phar".

[image: config]

3. I created simplest unittest to test if it is working and run test in PhpStorm

```html
<?php

class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testOneEqualsOne()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}

?>
```

Configured unit test to run in PhpStorm

[image: set unit test]

And run test in PhpStorm

[image: test]

I got error:

```
Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php on line 49

Call Stack:
    0.0000     372768   1. {main}() C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php:0
    0.0000     373120   2. IDE_PHPUnit_Loader::init() C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php:209
    0.0120     630736   3. IDE_PHPUnit_Loader::detectPHPUnitVersionId() C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php:196


Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php' (include_path='.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\pear') in C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php on line 49

Call Stack:
    0.0000     372768   1. {main}() C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php:0
    0.0000     373120   2. IDE_PHPUnit_Loader::init() C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php:209
    0.0120     630736   3. IDE_PHPUnit_Loader::detectPHPUnitVersionId() C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php:196


Process finished with exit code 255
```

When I run test via CMD, everything is ok.

[image: cmd]

**Question: How to setup PhpUnit via phpunit.phar to get it work?**

Comment: PhpStorm v8 does not support PHAR version of PHPUnit 4.6. Possible solutions: **1)** Install PHPUnit via Composer **2)** Use PhpStorm v9 EAP builds (it's fixed there) **3)** Try and hack PHPUnit support in PhpStorm a bit (check [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27333) for some details)

Comment: Possible solution, downgrade phpunit.phar to 3.7

Comment: Possible solution -- downgrade to 4.5 (no need for 3.x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhpStorm v8 does not support PHAR version of PHPUnit 4.6.

Solution:

- Use phpunit.phar version 4.5
- Use PhpStorm v9 EAP builds
- Try and hack PHPUnit support in PhpStorm a bit (detail [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27333))

Comment: And what about phpunit 5.0.8? PHPStorm v8 still doesn't support it?